# Drop with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have certain rows that I want to drop from the df1. I did write the conditions this way and showed me the exact rows that I wanted to delete. However, when I try to apply drop on this data, it doesn't work :

```
to_be deleted = df1.loc[df1['barcode'].str.contains('....-..-....-11.', regex=True)]
```

when I use

```
to_be deleted.head()
print(len(to_be deleted))
```

I can see the data that I want to delete, which means the code worked.
However, when I try drop these rows, it doesn't work

```
df2 = df1.drop([df1['barcode'].str.contains('....-..-....-11.', regex=True)], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

also I tried

```
df2 = df1.drop(to_be_deleted, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

but it either shows :

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

or

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

How can I drop these rows I specified in (to_be_deleted) data frame?

Thank you

Comment: The second answer in the linked question might be what you are looking for .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `pd.DataFrame.drop` for this:

```
mask = df1['barcode'].str.contains('....-..-....-11.', regex=True)

df1 = df1[~mask]
```

The `~` operator represents negation. Since `mask` is a Boolean array, it is negated and used as a row filter on `df1`.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. It works now.